# Using certificates in android client

Tags: android

I want to establish an ssl communication to the server from my android client.
this is what I've done so far:
1 Created a a pair of public private keys using java keytool genkey(and in the process        created a self signed certificate)
2. Exported the public key and imported the public key in to another keystore(called customkeystore)

Now I want to use this customkeystore file as my truststore. Where should I place this file in my android client and how to make it aware of the path of this trustore and access it.

Comment: You can try this.[Similar question is there. You can try my answer.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891174/client-certificate-android-https/20324240#20324240

Answer (score 0):

Don't know Android but I would imagine that you just load your keystore like in any Java application.
This is what happens here [SSL through Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441158/how-can-i-access-an-ssl-connection-through-android) and here [SSL Verification Android](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/SSLVerification_Android.aspx?display=Mobile)