# Use hardware-backed keys in SSLContext

Tags: android, security, keystore, sslcontext, secure-element

I'd like to use hardware backed keys for client-side mutual TLS on my Android.
The key should be unlocked with biometrics.

I have found how to generate hardware-backed keypairs on Android:

```
KeyPairGenerator keyGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance( KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, "AndroidKeyStore");
keyGenerator.initialize(
    new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(myAlias, KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
        .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256, KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
        .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
        .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
        .build());
keyGenerator.generateKeyPair();
```

and how to unlock the hardware-backed private key with a fingerprint:

```
FingerprintManager fingerprintManager = (FingerprintManager) this.getSystemService(Context.FINGERPRINT_SERVICE);
PrivateKey key  = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(myAlias, null);
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cipherAlgorithm, "AndroidKeyStore");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
FingerprintManager.CryptoObject cryptoObject = new FingerprintManager.CryptoObject(cipher);
fingerprintManager.authenticate(cryptoObject, cancellationSignal, 0, authenticationCallback, null);
```

I can also configure my HttpClient to use client certificates:

```
// I have loaded the PrivateKey privateKey and Certificate certificate from PEM files
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
keyStore.load(null);
final char pseudoSecretPassword[] = ("##" + System.currentTimeMillis()).toCharArray();
keyStore.setKeyEntry(
    PKIModule.DEFAULT_KEYSTORE_ALIAS,
    privateKey,
    pseudoSecretPassword,
    new Certificate[] {certificate}
);
KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
kmf.init(keyStore, pseudoSecretPassword);
KeyManager[] keyManagers = kmf.getKeyManagers();
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
sslContext.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, new SecureRandom());
OkHttpClient newClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .sslSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory())
    .build();
```

However I didn't find a way to directly unlock the hardware-backed private-key for use in a KeyManager used by the SSLContext, because the unlock mechanism works on crypto objects and not on private keys.

How can I make biometric key unlock and TLS client-certificates work together on Android?

## Update

Following @pedrofb points, I updated my code to generate the key-pair with `KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN` and `KeyProperties.DIGEST_NONE`. I signed the client key-pair with a CA that was imported into the server's truststore. As well as creating the client's KeyManager based on the AndroidKeyStore:

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
keyStore.load(null);
KeyManagerFactory factory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
factory.init(keyStore, null);
KeyManager[] keyManagers = factory.getKeyManagers();
sslContext.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, new SecureRandom());
```

However this fails with

```
W/CryptoUpcalls: Preferred provider doesn't support key:
W/System.err: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Keystore operation failed
        at android.security.KeyStore.getInvalidKeyException(KeyStore.java:1256)
        at android.security.KeyStore.getInvalidKeyException(KeyStore.java:1281)
        at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getInvalidKeyExceptionForInit(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:54)
        at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreSignatureSpiBase.ensureKeystoreOperationInitialized(AndroidKeyStoreSignatureSpiBase.java:219)
        at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreSignatureSpiBase.engineInitSign(AndroidKeyStoreSignatureSpiBase.java:99)
        at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreSignatureSpiBase.engineInitSign(AndroidKeyStoreSignatureSpiBase.java:77)
        at java.security.Signature$Delegate.init(Signature.java:1357)
        at java.security.Signature$Delegate.chooseProvider(Signature.java:1310)
        at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineInitSign(Signature.java:1385)
        at java.security.Signature.initSign(Signature.java:679)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.CryptoUpcalls.rawSignDigestWithPrivateKey(CryptoUpcalls.java:88)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.doHandshake(NativeSsl.java:383)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:231)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:336)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:300)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:185)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:224)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:107)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.java:87)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.Transmitter.newExchange(Transmitter.java:169)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:41)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:94)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:88)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:221)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:81)
        at com.jemmic.secuchat.biometriccrypto.MainActivity.testMutualTLS(MainActivity.java:402)
        at com.jemmic.secuchat.biometriccrypto.MainActivity.access$300(MainActivity.java:87)
        at com.jemmic.secuchat.biometriccrypto.MainActivity$TestMutualTlsTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:315)
        at com.jemmic.secuchat.biometriccrypto.MainActivity$TestMutualTlsTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:311)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
W/System.err: Caused by: android.security.KeyStoreException: Incompatible padding mode
        at android.security.KeyStore.getKeyStoreException(KeyStore.java:1159)
        ... 43 more
W/CryptoUpcalls: Could not find provider for algorithm: NONEwithRSA
```

Answer (score 1):

Some considerations:

- **The key is not hardware backed** unless the device has hardware support. You can check if a key is stored inside the secure hardware with `KeyInfo.isInsideSecurityHardware()`.
- **TLS requires digital signature but your key is created for encryption purposes**. You would need to change `KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT` with `KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN`
- **FingerprintManager encapsulates the use of the `Signature` object but it does not extends java.security.KeyStore** required by the default `KeyManager`

TLS requires to manage the private key directly, because the TLS protocol performs a signature over part of the shared data during handshake with a specific algorithm. To use FingerprintManager, the underlying cryptographic provider should support it directly.

I believe you can get the same result doing this:

1-  Unlock the desired key with the fingerprint

2-  Provide the AndroidKeyStore to the `KeyManagerFactory`

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
keyStore.load(null,null);
KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
kmf.init(keyStore, pseudoSecretPassword);
```

This solution I think could work, but y**ou will need to associate a certificate to the private key that matches the list of accepted CAs that the server sends**, therefore you will have to issue a certificate using the public key and store it in the android keystore associated with the private key.

You have not mentioned if you are going to use a solution of this style, which is quite complex

If you are not going to use certificates, you could write your own `KeyManager` to retrieve the right `PrivateKey` during TLS handshake. Look at my answer here, it's quite similar to your use case but using AndroidKeyChain instead of AndroidKeyStore

[Request with automatic or user selection of appropriate client certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44929645/request-with-automatic-or-user-selection-of-appropriate-client-certificate/45035052#45035052)

Comment: Good points about having to check for `KeyInfo.isInsideSecurityHardware()` and needing `KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT` and `KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN`.

Additionally `.setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_NONE, ...)` might be required (https://github.com/google/conscrypt/issues/497).